# How to get the error id of a given line in flycheck?

Tags: flycheck

I would like a function to return the flycheck error id for the piece of code my cursor is over. Pylint is my main interest.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `flycheck-copy-errors-as-kill` with a normal argument you will get the desired effect (list's first entry).

- `C-u 1 M-x flycheck-copy-errors-as-kill` will add the **error id** to the kill ring.
- `C-u M-x flycheck-copy-errors-as-kill` will add the error id and the message to the kill ring.
- `M-x flycheck-copy-errors-as-kill` will add the the error message to the kill ring.